# Symfony 4.3 does not read .env when ran in a docker container

Tags: docker, symfony

I have my Symfony application run perfectly fine on my development machine, on several servers except for one where it doesn't read the `.env` file.

The env file contains this variable:

```
root@719c10cf645d:/app# grep application_version .env
application_version=3.0.3-64-g642ed7f
```

The shell environment doesn't:

```
root@719c10cf645d:/app# env | grep application_version
root@719c10cf645d:/app# set | grep application_version
```

Symfony doesn't read the `.env` file:

```
root@719c10cf645d:/app# ./bin/console >/dev/null

 [WARNING] Some commands could not be registered:

In EnvVarProcessor.php line 131:

  Environment variable not found: "application_version".



 [WARNING] Some commands could not be registered:

In EnvVarProcessor.php line 131:

  Environment variable not found: "application_version".
```

On another server I have:

```
root@4535704c813a:/app# env | grep application_version
root@4535704c813a:/app# set | grep application_version
root@4535704c813a:/app# grep application_version .env
application_version=3.0.3-64-g642ed7f
root@4535704c813a:/app# ./bin/console >/dev/null
root@4535704c813a:/app#
```

I'm using the same docker version (19.03.5, build 633a0ea838) on both servers, same OS (Debian), and same docker images (different registry, but same SHA1). So everything should be perfectly identical.

What could be wrong here?

Comment: have you cleared the cache? another classic is permissions, but since you're running as root, that shouldn't be the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The environment on the two servers were different, and my `config/bootstrap.php` file didn't load `.env` files on one machine.

The bottom line is that I didn't follow these updates: https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/dot-env-changes.html

I don't know how my app survived without these changes for one year.